# Poor performance of XML transform in Scala

Tags: xml, scala

I am trying to understand an XML transform performance problem:

Suppose I need to change the label of all elements with label `a` to label `b`.

```
val xml = ... // my input XML

val rule = new RewriteRule {
  override def transform(n: Node) = n match {
    case e: Elem if e.label == "a" => e.copy(label = "b")
    case other => other 
  }
}

new RuleTransformer(rule).apply(xml)
```

Unfortunately, when I run that code with an XML of ~30 elements it takes `> 1 min (!)` in a modern laptop.

For example:

```
scala> def gen(e: Elem, n: Int): Elem = 
       | if (n > 0) e.copy(child = e.child :+ gen(e, n-1)) else e
gen: (e: scala.xml.Elem, n: Int)scala.xml.Elem

scala> val xml = gen(<a/>, 25)
xml: scala.xml.Elem = <a><a><a><a><a><a><a> ...

scala> val rule = new RewriteRule {
       | override def transform(n : Node) = n match {
       | case e: Elem if e.label == "a" => e.copy(label = "b")
       | case other => other
       | }
       | }
rule: scala.xml.transform.RewriteRule = <function1>

scala> def transform(n: Node): Node = { 
       | val start = System.currentTimeMillis()
       | val r = new RuleTransformer(rule).apply(n)
       | println((System.currentTimeMillis() - start) / 1000)
       | r
       | }
transform: (n: scala.xml.Node)scala.xml.Node

scala> transform(xml)
99
```

Does such performance make sense ? Am I missing something ? How would you fix the code ?

Comment: I guess that e.copy makes a deep copy (inefficient) so your algorithm runs in quadratic time overall… and what if you try to use a library which is created with performance in mind?

Comment: @SargeBorsch It does not do a _deep_ copy according to the sources. What library would you recommend ?

Comment: Can you describe the structure of your XML in a little more detail? I can't imagine how you'd see that kind of performance on a few dozen elements.

Comment: @TravisBrown I have updated the question with an example I have tried in REPL

Comment: Turns out that the performance is indeed that bad.  It runs in O(2^n).  There is a detailed discussion of it [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30861880/is-complexity-of-scala-xml-ruletransformer-really-exponential)

Comment: I faced similar performance issues with default Scala Xml. So switched to the [vtd-xml](http://vtd-xml.sourceforge.net/) Java library. vtd-xml is not as straightforward to use but is kick-ass when it comes to performance

Comment: https://www.wix.engineering/single-post/a-tale-of-two-xml-transformations-2 seems useful

Comment: If you use Scala 2.12 it's running OK (0 seconds reported by the posted example code)

Comment: other thing to try and use in databricks.xml library to convert the XML into dataframe and do you processing on the dataframe itself.