# Function to transform XML instead of RuleTransformer

Tags: xml, scala

This is a follow-up to my previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30330951/poor-performance-of-xml-transform-in-scala).

I have written a simple function, which transforms an XML much faster than `RuleTransformer`

```
def trans(node: Node, pf: PartialFunction[Node, Node]): Node = {
  val n1 = if (pf.isDefinedAt(node)) pf(node) else node
  n1 match {
    case e: Elem => e.copy(child = e.child map (c => trans(c, pf)))
    case other => other
  }
}
```

Does it make sense ? How would you correct/improve that code ?

Answer (score 1):

I seem to be allergic to `if` statements these days, so if it was my code, the only adjustment would be using [`PartialFunction`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.PartialFunction)'s `applyOrElse` to eliminate that:

```
def trans2(node: Node, pf: PartialFunction[Node, Node]): Node = {
  val n1 = pf.applyOrElse(node, identity[Node])
  n1 match {
    case e: Elem => e.copy(child = e.child map (c => trans2(c, pf)))
    case other => other
  }
}
```

I'm the first to admit that the "obviousness" may well have been reduced :-(

Comment: Thank you. Did not know about `applyOrElse`.